# ERROR @react-navigation/bottom-tabs could not be found within the project

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[image: 1]

Hi there! I'm developing applications in visual studio code with react native but I'm getting this error in the bottom tab navigation section.Can you help?

wherever the problem is, I would be very glad if you could tell me how to fix it